# CodeIgniter can't find CI_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get CodeIgniter running on my testserver (using XAMPP). I have set up everything like i usually do, plus I've copied all of the files from a working installation on my web server and just changed the necessary config options:

1. `Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in D:\Websites\****\www\application\controllers\main.php on line 4`
2. `Message: Undefined index: scaffolding_trigger, Filename: libraries/Router.php`

I'm pretty sure my controller is set-up properly, but in case it isn't here's the setup:

```
class Speaker extends CI_Controller
{
     function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper('url');
     }
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try without __construct()? Also, I note that the error refers to main.php, but your class is named Speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah I hate how you finally find the problem right as you ask the question haha

I decided to check out my system folder and found it was out of sync with what I had on my server. Just updated it and everything's working.

Comment: What do you mean "out of sync with"?? How did you fix the problem?

Comment: I was in the midst of upgrading my Codeigniter version and had upgraded the files in the application folder (2.0 changes Controller to CI_Controller) but not in the system folder.

Answer (score -1):

You only extend CI_Controller if you are using CodeIgniter 2.0.x as 1.7.x extends Controller.